# Why after changing ideal OPAMP to a real one, there appeared bounding in negative part of the sine wave(Proteus)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, proteus, active-filter

I am trying to get sine wave from square wave (555 timer) by applying low pass filter. For ideal OP-AMP it works fine, but when I changed it to 741 for example, there appeared some bounding of low part. Could you please suggest why it is?

741:
[image: 741]

The circuit:
[image]

Comment: Because real opamp output is clipped with a voltage lower than the supply by a certain amount, usually found in the datatsheet

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see... Actually I need +-0.5 at the output, but I reduce it after filtering. Do u think is better to reduce the voltage before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a 741 on +15 V and -15 V power rails, the output might be able to give you a voltage of +/-13 volts. That's a broad-brushed typical value. The guaranteed value is +/-12 volts.

You could try coupling the output from the 555 via a 10 uF capacitor if you don't need the DC level to be fed through the filter.

Comment: Actually, I have +-15V power rails (-15v is not seen on the circuit, but it there). And have clipped wave on -13V =(

Comment: I did say "+15 V and -15 V power rails". It clips at a negative voltage because the op-amp filter is configured as an inverter.

Comment: Thanks, after adding 10uF capacitor I have a nice sine wave -5 to -10V, Now i need to reduce and shift it to get +-0.5V on the output. Thanks again

Comment: If you let the simulator extend its timebase you would find it settles to a value that is symmetrical about 0 volts. Try a smaller value of capacitor to help you see this. To get the signal smaller I'd be tempted to increase the 910 R resistor by about ten and use a 1kohm to ground across C5 - it won't be exact but it will give you an idea what to do component wise.

Comment: Fine, it works. Now it works as voltage divider before filtering, right? but will it reduce slowly to zero now, or will remain the same? I used 5.6k resistance instead of 910, and have 10uF in parallel with 1k resistor on the output of 555

Comment: From 555 output you have the 10 uF then a 10k ohm resistor in series. This series arrangement connect to the top of C5. In parallel with C5 you have a 1 kohm resistor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52486/discussion-between-taras-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping, especially [Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka).

Basically, to get rid of DC was added capacitor, it made a high pass filter.

Here is my circuit:

[image]